# Laravel: Migrations do not work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migration

I have created a file Order.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'order';
}
```

Then I have created a migration, called 2016_01_01_111111_create_orders_table.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('order', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('orderIdent');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Then I did the migration with

```
php artisan migrate
```

Then, I wanted to add some fields, created a new migration file called 2016_01_02_111111_alter_orders.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AlterOrders extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::table('order', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->string('selecteddate');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Then again I did

```
php artisan migrate
```

But now I get this message in console:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                                                        
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'order' already exists
```

What do I need to do, to add the new fields to my table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should be correct, are you sure you didn't rename the filename of the migrations? As far as I know the filename is saved in the migrations table so if it's changed it will be assumed to be a different migration

Comment: You didn't rollback your migration at any point, did you? You don't have anything in your down function.

Comment: If you've rolled back your migration, then it "undid" the changes and removed the migration from it's processed list (the migrations table in the database). it's most likely trying to run that first migration again. You should always fill in the down function to undo your changes in case you rollback.

Comment: ok, so what do i need to do? in the first migration, all fields in the up should also be in the down function? in the second migration, the same?

Comment: and, more important, how can I come to a fresh state now? should i delete the migrations table?

Comment: Correct for adding to the down function. And at this point, just comment out the innards of the up function of the first migration, so it will skip over it. Just make sure to uncomment it when you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as an answer vs a comment to show what needs to be done. Since rollback was done, up needs to be commented out for now.

```
public function up()
{ /*
    Schema::create('order', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('orderIdent');
        $table->timestamps();
    }); */
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('order');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 `public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::table('order', function($table)
        {
            $table->string('selecteddate');
        });
    }`

remove `Blueprint`.

Comment: the same as before: [PDOException]                                                                         
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'order' already exists

Comment: Why should OP remove the typehinting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```